# Div box expand and re-position other div boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

so i'm making a project and I want the three box style page, however when I do the auto-expand to fit the content inside the boxes it floats over the other boxes - as I have had to position them.

html code:

```
<div class="content">
    <h2>Contact me</h2>
    <p>--content holder--</p>
</div>

<div class="content-bottom-left">
    <p>--content holder--</p>
</div>
<div class="content-bottom-right">
    <p>--content holder--</p>
</div>
```

my CSS:

```
.content {
    background-color: 373737;
    top: 15%;
    width: 55%;
    right: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.content-bottom-left {
    background-color: 373737;
    width: 27%;
    left: 15%;
    top: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content-bottom-right {
    background-color: 373737;
    width: 27%;
    right: 20%;
    top: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Outcome: 
[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlyZg.png)

Answer (score 0):

add this CSS rule to your Div tags:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS doesn't allow the positions of the elements to move with above content
adding the following to both of the lower should do it.

```
clear: both;
```

tells elements to avoid collisions with elements on their left and right with which they collide, along with behnam bozorg's comment it should work.
You might also remove the top absolute positioning as it is being pushed down anyways.

```
.content-bottom-left {

    background-color: 373737;
    width: 27%;
    left: 15%;
    top: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content-bottom-right {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: 373737;
    width: 27%;
    right: 20%;
    top: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me :/ it doesn't change anything.